# Manipulação de horas com Joda Time

Tags: java, jodatime

```
 String tempo1 = "01:30:30";
 String tempo2 = "24:25:10";

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        Date date1 = (Date)sdf.parse(tempo1);
        Date date2 = (Date)sdf.parse(tempo2);

        DateTime dateTime1 = new DateTime(date1);
        DateTime dateTime2 = new DateTime(date2);
```

Pessoal, como faço pra somar essas duas Strings que fique da seguinte forma: "25:55:40"?

Tá sempre retornando 01:55:40.

Comment: Não creio que seja duplicata @DiegoF pois a pergunta se refere à soma de tempos utilizando JodaTime e não Java puro.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando JodaTime creio eu que a seguinte função resolveria seu problema:

```
private DateTime somarTempos(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) {
    return t1.plusHours(t2.getHourOfDay())
            .plusMinutes(t2.getMinuteOfHour())
            .plusSeconds(t2.getSecondOfMinute());
}
```